# Java accessing files and folders in classpath

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, web

I am developing an application in Spring-Boot with an embedded tomcat server.
My program downloads documents to the public class path inside the resources folder. Also I am accessing the files downloaded in Iframe tag in HTML, so the file should be in server for me to access it.

When I run the code from my eclipse IDE , it works fine, and I am able to access the files but when I run the war from the command prompt(Since it has an embedded tomcat server) I am unable to locate the folders. Please note that I opened the war and was able to find the folders but the program couldn`t access it.

Any Idea on how to access class resources folder from tomcat embedded war in java? Any help would be much appreciated.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream inputDataStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("some-file.txt");
```